# Github Environment Protection Rules Multiple Approvals

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to setup an Environment Protection Rule such that it requires multiple reviewers before it proceeds?

When setting up branch protection rules, you can require multiple approvals before merging is allowed.  I would like to do the same for environment protection rules, but I only see the ability to require any number of reviewers.

I am open to clever workarounds, though I would really like something that is natively supported with as few hacks as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!

We can create a group in the GitHub teams and add members. ADD the group to the environments "Required reviewers"

Comment: This requires all members of the group approve, or only one member of the group to approve?  I need something that requires multiple approvals from different people.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Specifically for 2 approvals, it appears that GitHub Environments now have an option for "Require a different approver than the user who triggered the workflow run."  We could probably setup the release job to be manually triggered and set this flag to true so that a second, different, person would have to approve the job.  This solution wouldn't work for more than 2 reviewers though.

**ORIGINAL**: The way we eventually solved this was a bit of a hack, though ended up not being too bad.  First we created two GitHub Environments, each with "Required Reviewers" set with all of our team on each.  Then we setup the following GitHub action which won't run until both approval jobs complete, and the `upload` task will fail if the same person approved both approval jobs.

```yaml
  approve1:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      environment: Approve1
      needs: release
      steps:
        - name: No Op
          id: no_op
          run: |
            echo Do Nothing
  approve2:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      environment: Approve2
      needs: release
      steps:
        - name: No Op
          id: no_op
          run: |
            echo Do Nothing
  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      - approve1
      - approve2
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v4
        with:
          script: |
            // Get the approvals for this run
            const approvals = await github.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/{run_id}/approvals', {
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              run_id: context.runId
            })
            const users = approvals.data.filter(approval => approval.user.type === 'User')
            const distinctUsernames = Array.from(new Set(users.map(user => user.user.login)))
            // Empty check
            if (distinctUsernames.length < 2){
              core.setFailed(`Did not receive the required 2 distinct approvals for this deployment. Approved Users: ${distinctUsernames.join(",")}`);
              return;
            }
      - ...
```